# Why is this string value a number?

Tags: ruby

In the Ruby Koans, you have to fill in the blank for what represents `string[1]` below. Why is the answer 97?

```
def test_you_can_get_a_single_character_from_a_string
  string = "Bacon, lettuce and tomato"
  assert_equal ___ , string[1]
end
```

Comment: Where did you get the koan from? That koan got changed [in March](https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/commit/a46642e192844a312c344d43147a81ecf43f438b).

Comment: What were you expecting the answer to be?

Comment: Andrew, http://koans.heroku.com

Comment: Karl, wasn't expecting a decimal but 'a' itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

97 is the ASCII decimal representation of 'a', which is the the letter located at string[1].

Comment: And in Ruby 1.9, the result of `string[1]` is `"a"`.

Comment: Yup, in Ruby 1.9 this koan is no longer correct:

`$ irb
1.9.2p290 :001 > string = "aaaaa"
 => "aaaaa" 
1.9.2p290 :002 > string[1]
 => "a"`

Ruby 1.8:

`$ irb
>> string = "aaaaa"
=> "aaaaa"
>> string[1]
=> 97`

Answer (score 2):

97 is the ASCII value (in decimal) for the lowercase a.

Answer (score 2):

`string[1]` will give you the second character of string, the first being 0. This is converted to an integer, 'a' being represented as 97 in [ASCII](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange). So this gives you 97.